# Unable to use Sphinx MVA sql_attr_multi

Tags: sphinx, multivalue

I have a field called "tags" and it has values (say) "Music, Art, Sports, Food" etc. How can I use setFilter function in PHP-Sphinx for this field. I know that it has to be an integer and should be used as an array in PHP. So, if I use a numeric field for tags, what about the delimiters (in this case comma). Currently, I am using "sql_attr_multi" like this…

```
sql_attr_multi = uint tags from field
```

I have to filter the search based on any of the keywords the user has selected, Music, Sports, Food etc. As such, only MVA is the right option to do this. But I am just not able to figure out, how to do this. I can store all tag elements as numeric values and make the tags field as int. But what about the comma or how will I convert the whole string (Music, Art, Sports, Food) as an integer. Later, how do I call setFilter using PHP.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well using a MVA, suggests you already unique-ids for each tag.

Which if you had a seperate table for tags (with a PK), and many-to-many table joining your documents, and tags. (thats a very common way to store tags - in normal form)

If you have a text column containing the text, would be easier to just use a Field. Can easily filter by fields in the main text-query.

crispy creams @tags Food

for example (thats extended mode query)

(But fields can't do Grouping like you can with Attributes)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I am not understanding this at all. May be my question is not clear. I will elaborate the situation more clearly with example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827965/sphinx-multi-value-attribute-filter Any help would be highly appreciated.