# Sphinx multi value attribute filter

Tags: filter, sphinx, multivalue

Yes, each tag has unique Id. It is not necessary that I have to store these unique id's in a table. I can store them in this way…

```
$tags = array("Music","Sports","Food","Books",………)
```

Array is the best way for me as it is easily alterable. Moreover the array keys itself will serve as the unique Id's.

But my situation is more critical, so let me elaborate the exact situation.

I have a single table with fields like Id, Title, Description, Tags, etc. etc. etc.

```
Id  |    Title      |  Description                     |  Tags  
1   | Sport & Hygine| With sport & music good food is …| Sport, Food
2   | Rock Concert  | Great Rock Show at …             | Music, Dance
```

If a user selects (filter) to show records, that has Music in the Tags field. Although the Title and description does not have the word Music at all in the second row, but still it should get the first priority. Also it should be noted that Title and Description are text fields and Sphinx should search the normal way giving appropriate Weights and Ranks to Titles and Description. But Tags field cannot be searched as text indexing. Tags field needs to be filtered.

Therefore, in the above example, if Music is selected, then row 2 should only be displayed, because it is filtered based on Tags and Row 2 only has Music in the Tags field. But Music is also present in Row 1 in the Description field, but here it should be ignored. I hope I am able to clarify the situation. Any hep with this is highly appreciated.

Comment: For people confused by the refernces in this question, seems to be intended as a contination of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17815548/unable-to-use-sphinx-mva-sql-attr-multi

Answer (score 0):

The unique-id needs to be unique across all documents. So that "Sports" would have the same ID on all documents, and therefore the same ID can be used for searching. So you search for the ID, not the word.

So the tags can be used to influence ranking, you can put them in a Field. But ALSO store the tag-ids in a MVA, so can use for setFilter.

Something like

Music @tags Music

should work as an extended query. BEcause it requires the word Music in Tags. But also the first term will match all feilds and help with ranking.

Comment: They all have unique Id (say) Music has Id 1, Sports has Id 2 and so on. Then the tags field data in the table will be something like this 2,3 for Row 1 and 1,5 for Row 2 and so on. As stated in the original Question, here we are getting Commas like 2,3 etc. As such, this field is never numeric (it's a combination of numbers and comma), then how can we apply setFilter. Because setFilter has to applied for fields that are integers. Had it been a single number, I could always use setFilter. Also, I am not understanding how you represent Music @tags Music or basically what it means.

Comment: You pass a string to sphinx during indexing (if its compused during the sql_query, or an actual textual column it doesnt matter). Sphinx will automatically parse "a list of numbers seperated by commas" and store it in the MVA. It attachs multiple id's to each document.

Comment: Or do you mean that I should have another separate table called Tags. This Tags table will have fields Id, Tag. Then in the sphinx src, I will write something like this...sql_attr_multi = uint tags from query;SELECT Id, Tag FROM Tags

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how do you pass a string during indexing. I run the indexer from the UNIX command line, like this : indexer --config sphinx.conf test1 where test1 is the document that I am indexing. So, how do I pass string during indexing...

Comment: in the `sql_query` config.